# Assembly.loadFrom failing because of version

Tags: c#, windows, dll

I have a very thin client exe that loads all its DLLs dynamically with Assembly.LoadFrom(). I do this so it can download new DLLs, and then load them seamlessly. I cannot just download a whole new MSI due to outside requirements.

My issue is if my initial build is labeled 1.0.0.0, and then the new DLLs are labeled 1.0.0.1, they fail to load. I haven't found any documentation on this, but it is definitely dependent on the version of the DLL. To clarify, these are DLLs written by me, not nuget packages.

Does anybody know how to get around this?